# how to add large amounts of HTML to IE without crippling the CPU

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer, dom

i've been experimenting with a more ajax approach to loading data on a page, mostly to avoid postbacks. i can easily acquire server-constructed html via an ajax call and adding it to the dom is simple enough with the help of jquery's .append or .replaceWith. both of these methods are extremely fast in chrome/firefox but terribly slow in ie (7,8,9).

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function (responseHtml)
    {
            //document.getElementById('targetElementId').outerHTML = responseHtml;
            $('#targetElementId').replaceWith(responseHtml);
    }
});
```

you will see from my code block, i've also attempted to use a non-jquery approach. both lines perform horrendously in ie. so my question, what is the best practice for adding large amounts of html to a page so it doesnt crush ie?

Comment: What is responseHtml? Are you just making this call once? If it is as simple as your example looks, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: ie dude! fast he will never be :(

Comment: @BNL responseHtml is pure mark up from the server. the call occurs on-demand for loading. in one instance, i'm using it for filtering a dynamic table (currently reloaded via postbacks).

Comment: not sure if this helps or not, but should make the code look cleaner: $('#targetElementId').load(url)

Comment: @Rodolfo .load would do the same thing. also, i cant cache so i'm guessing the url would need some randomly generated value. jquery's cache: false handles this nicely for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you're better off returning JSON to the browser, and using a template plugin like jQuery tmpl to map the json to the HTML to display, since tmpl does some wonderful caching that speeds performance in slower browsers like IE. It also makes the JSON response snappier. Example:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <span class="message">${text}</span>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
             $("#targetElementId").html($("#template").tmpl(data));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Your JSON response would need to be formatted such that it matched the template:

```
{ text: "Blah!" }
```

Comment: LOL that just adds one more additional step

Comment: Not quite. Returning JSON saves data transfer, on top of the HTML generation being cached so performance is only impacted the first time the template is used, meaning a snappier response in IE.

Comment: @d_r_w i use this approach elsewhere in the project, the reason i dont use it here is due to the size. returning JSON is limited to <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2097152"/>.

Comment: You're returning that much data in a single AJAX request? That might be why it's running so slow in IE.

Comment: @d_r_w ie handles the request size just fine. if i remove all the dom processing its just as fast as the other browsers.

Comment: Understandable. What I mean is that if you're pushing along that much HTML in a single AJAX request, perhaps it is best to cut it down in some respects. Not for the sake of heavy data transfer affecting IE (because it really doesn't), but for the sake of having so much HTML to process. Why would you need so much HTML for an AJAX request?

Comment: @d_r_w sorry for the long delay, the idea was for paging/sorting a large data table. with a little work, i think the original idea of templating would be sufficient. you're right, its just too much data and bad practice to pass all that around.

Answer (score 1):

You can try .text() or .html().

Comment: I've seen tests that mention DOM manipulation in IE is much slower, maybe doing replacewith is using this method. Instead, trying javascript .innerHTML = responseHTML could improve speed (which might be the same as using .text or .html as you suggest)